# What's the meaning and use of しまわれました in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, keigo, sonkeigo

I'm doing an exercise in my textbook on 尊敬語、and there's a sentence that I don't understand well.

The sentence is:

> もう論文かいてしまわれましたか｡

Is "しまわれました" the past tense of "いる"?

If so, with the 尊敬語 shouldn't it be "いらっしゃいました"?.

I'm a bit confused about this, if anyone can please help me understand I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

The past tense of いる is of course いた, but the verb いる is not used in the first place, and いらっしゃいました is not relevant at all. The verb you're actually seeing is 書く ("to write"). The object marker を is omitted after 論文.

To break down,

- 書いて: the te-form of 書く
- しまわ: the 未然形/pre-nai-form of しまう, which in this case means "to finish ～ing".
- れ: the continuative- (or pre-masu-) form of れる, which in this case is to show respect to the action taker
- ました: the ta-form/past-tense of ます
- か: question marker

> もう論文[書いて]{かいて}しまわれましたか｡
>   Have you already finished writing your (academic) article?

Comment: Oh thank you for the clear explanation, this solve every doubt (｡•ᴗ•｡)♡

Answer (score 0):

The past tense of いる is いた and いた becomes いらっしゃった or いらっしゃいました as the 尊敬語. Also, しまわれました is the past tense of する as the 尊敬語.

By the way, I feel something wrong with the sentence on your textbook "もう論文かいてしまわれましたか". It might be grammatically correct, but "もう論文を書かれましたか" would be better.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Isn't the past tense of する in sonkeigo なさいました or されました？This is just my assumption because なさる and される would be the plain form in sonkeigo... Or am I forgetting something?

Comment: "しまわれました is the past tense of **する** as the 尊敬語" <-- Really? しまわれました is the past respectful form of **しまう** , no? しまう→(honorific)しまわれる→(past)しまわれた→(polite form)しまわれました

Comment: Sorry my mistake. The 尊敬語 of する is なさる or される. You guys are correct!